# Automatically fixing ill-conditioning or collinearity

Tags: feature-selection, multicollinearity, covariance-matrix, condition-number

I'm backtesting a regression model, which entails running it on a bunch of bootstrap samples of a "rewound" version of our data set. Unfortunately, in some of these resamplings, I end up getting some "coincidental" dependencies between covariates that result in a covariate matrix that's either rank-deficient or ill-conditioned (on that specific bootstrap sample; the full covariate matrix is not ill-conditioned). Obviously this causes difficulties for inference.

Is there a standard way of solving this automatically/algorithmically? If I were only fitting on one dataset, I'd simply drop one of the features causing the rank deficiency/ill-conditioning, but that's impractical to do for 20 bootstrap samples of 12 different time snapshots.

My default plan is just to switch to penalized regression, but I'm wondering if there's a more principled approach, since I have enough data that I definitely don't need the penalty otherwise.

Comment: I added the `variance-covariance` tag as this concerns a VCV matrix; I hope you are OK with it.

Comment: MATLAB has a relatively new equilibrate function for matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use your original matrix $K$, you might want to use a $K^{\prime}$ that is the closest you can get in terms of Frobenius norm. To do that find the smallest eigenvalues and set them to a higher number positive number. This will give you a new P(S)D matrix that is closer than any other matrix in Frobenius norm, see [N.J. Higham 1988](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/narep/narep126.pdf) for details.

You can also consider using [Tikhonov regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization). In that case you essentially do a ridge regression-like correction. As you original matrix $K$ will become $K^{\prime} = K + \lambda I$, you will add $\lambda$ to all your eigenvalues. While a bit simplistic this choice has a very nice statistical interpretation: you practically say that all your samples are bit ($\lambda$) more noisy than before (and because as you add things along the diagonal no covariances are affected).

I do not touch at all at [alternating projection methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projections_onto_convex_sets) for this matter. You can read more about it on this [blog-post](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/the-nearest-correlation-matrix/) by Higham; it offers a nice discussion, as well as links to software implement these procedures in R, MATLAB, Python.

It goes without saying that these methods change the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of the matrix you are examining. In *most cases* the new matrix will have a lower condition number as the ratio of the largest singular value of that matrix to the smallest singular value will get smaller, this is not guaranteed to happen though.